# Confirmation of Licence violation in case of Using Mobile App .net server deployed on self-hosted server

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing Mobile App .Net server and want to use the service on self hosted servers for production usage. The service will be deployed on IIS instead of Azure portal. I am working on offline data sync feature using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server package. And for client Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client is being used. And all these packages and dependent libraries are open source as its available on github.

So, what about its licencing? Is there any limitation or licencing clause that restricts from using these applications without Azure portal?
Or its free to use?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, these libraries are open source licensed with Apache 2.0. So, you can use them without any problem, as long as you mention the original authors.